# Swift Array remove only one item with a specific value

Tags: arrays, swift3

Alright, this should not be too difficult, but Sunday morning proves me wrong...

I have an `Array` with structs, and want to remove only one struct that matches its name property to a `String`. For example:

```
struct Person {
   let name: String
}

var myPersons =
[Person(name: "Jim"),
 Person(name: "Bob"),
 Person(name: "Julie"),
 Person(name: "Bob")]

func removePersonsWith(name: String) {
   myPersons = myPersons.filter { $0.name != name }
}

removePersonsWith(name: "Bob")
print(myPersons)
```

results in:

```
[Person(name: "Jim"), Person(name: "Julie")]
```

But how do I only remove *one* Bob?

Comment: tell me what differentiates between the two Bobs, then I'll tell you how. But if not, you can set a bool flag so once the filter is set to false it would exit the loop

Comment: The two Bobs are exactly the same, they are clones of each other, but I only want to remove one of them.

Comment: I'm just curious that why are you up to such functionality? Is it to remove duplicates? Or something else?

Comment: `Person` is just an example. I could have used a different example, eg balls with different colors, and then remove one red ball. Or fish in a river, and catch (remove) one salmon, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `filter` filters **all items** which match the condition.
- `firstIndex` returns the index of the **first item** which matches the condition.

  ```
    func removePersonsWith(name: String) {
        if let index = myPersons.firstIndex(where: {$0.name == name}) {
            myPersons.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
  ```

However the name of the function is misleading. It's supposed to be `removeAPersonWith` ;-)

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP eventually wants. He wants to erase all but one ie if he has 5 Bobs, he would want to remove 4 of them, this on removes 1 of them. Koen, please let us know what you want. Otherwise good answer

Comment: No, I only want to remove one Bob

Comment: In terms of naming, I would call the method `removeFirstPersonWith(name: String)` to make it a little more clear.

Comment: @AllanSpreys I mentioned the ambiguity in the answer.

Comment: Yes, I know :) I’m recommending an alternative to those who find the answer helpful.